# Animar con javascript un div

Tags: javascript, html, css

como hago para animar un div para que aparezca con un efecto fadeIn pero con javascript y no Jquery? Ya probe con ponerle transition y animate en css y no anda. Tambien probe con ponerle opacity 0 y en JS opacity 1. Visibility hidden.

```js
function lightMenu () {
var menuMenu = document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "none";
var menuMenuDos = document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "block";
 if (menuMenu != menuMenuDos) {
  menuMenu.style.display = "block"; 
 }
}

function offMenu () {
var menuMenu = document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "block";
var menuMenuDos = document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "none";
 if (menuMenu != menuMenuDos) {
  menuMenu.style.display = "none"; 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno leí que tienes problemas al tratar de hacerlo con css y javascript, lo importante seria crear una clase donde le indique el comportamiento en cuanto visibilidad así:

```js
const mostrar = () => {
 document.querySelector(".recuadro").classList.remove("ocultar");
}

const ocultar = () => {
 document.querySelector(".recuadro").classList.add("ocultar");
}
```

```css
.recuadro{
  border:1px solid red;
  height:100px;
  transition: all .7s;
  width:100px;
}

.ocultar{
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="recuadro"></div>
<button onclick="mostrar()">Mostrar</button>
<button onclick="ocultar()">Ocultar</button>
```

El truco está en declarar en la clase que tiene el **DIV** una propiedad llamada **transition** donde le indicas el efecto que quieres y los mili-segundos que tardará en terminar el efecto, en este caso coloque que todos **"all"** efectos tarden 0.7 segundos, puedes reemplazar el **all** por cualquier propiedad en especifica, en este caso **opacity** así:

```js
const mostrar = () => {
 document.querySelector(".recuadro").classList.remove("ocultar");
}

const ocultar = () => {
 document.querySelector(".recuadro").classList.add("ocultar");
}
```

```css
.recuadro{
  border:1px solid red;
  height:100px;
  transition: opacity .7s;
  width:100px;
}

.ocultar{
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="recuadro"></div>
<button onclick="mostrar()">Mostrar</button>
<button onclick="ocultar()">Ocultar</button>
```

Luego declaras una clase que te permita realizar el efecto que quiere una vez que tenga dicha clase, en este caso la clase **ocultar** con la propiedad **opacity** la cual se encarga de colocarlo transparente.

Puedes hacerlo netamente con Javascript? si claro que si, pero recomiendo que separes todo lo que tiene de javascript del css así tienes un orden y solo te limitas en tu JS en agregar o remover una clase y en el **CSS** te ocupas de tu estilo.

**VERSIÓN CON TOGGLE**

Una versión reducida del codigo anterior seria usando toggle así:

```js
const mostrarOcultar = () => {
 document.querySelector(".recuadro").classList.toggle("ocultar");
}
```

```css
.recuadro{
  border:1px solid red;
  height:100px;
  transition: opacity .7s;
  width:100px;
}

.ocultar{
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="recuadro"></div>
<button onclick="mostrarOcultar ()">Mostrar / Ocultar</button>
```

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Debes de temporizar el cambio de opacidad, así debería de funcionar, cualquier duda hazla saber.

```js
let btn1 = document.getElementById('ocultar');
btn1.addEventListener('click', ocultar);

let btn2 = document.getElementById('mostrar');
btn2.addEventListener('click', mostrar);

function ocultar() {
for (i = 10; i >= 0; i--)
 setTimeout("document.getElementById('contenedor').style.opacity = '" + (i / 10) + "'", (10 - i) * 100)
}


function mostrar() {
for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
 setTimeout("document.getElementById('contenedor').style.opacity = '" + (i / 10) + "'", i * 100)
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">cajita</div>

<button id="ocultar">Ocultar</button>
<button id="mostrar">Mostra</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function show(){
  document.querySelector("#aocultar").class="show"
}
function hide(){
  document.querySelector("#aocultar").class="hide"
}
```

```css
#aocultar{
  transition: all .5s;
}

#aocultar.hide{
  opacity: 0;
}

#aocultar.show{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="aocultar" >Div a ocultar</div>
<button onclick="show()">hide</button>
<button onclick="hide()">show</button>
```